# RegEx: get everything after curly braces

Tags: python, regex, trim

I got node names from an XML file that contain a namespace:

> {http://datex2.eu/schema/2/2_0}nodeName

From this I would like to trim the namespace, which is in curly braces. So the result should be the node name only. Could be **either matching all contents in curly braces** with a RegEx and then removing them from the string. **Or matching the content after** the braces directly. But I'm too stupid to get the Regex right ...

Thanks for any help!

PS: I'm coding in Python 3.

Comment: Hello, what did you try?

Comment: `re.sub("{.*?}", "", nodeName)`

Comment: [`{[^}]+}(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/vq8k3E/2) ?..

Comment: Question. Did you add the curly braces or do they actually exist in the nodeName?

Comment: @MarounMaroun your first RegEx found everything and the first part finds the content with the curly braces. Any modification to find just the node name?

Comment: @COLDSPEED the braces are in the XML and node name, not added by me.

Comment: @Matthias the result you want is in the *first captured group* of the regex.

Comment: Did you try what I posted? Rather than capture groups, it just removes what you don't want, which I think is simpler.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yeah, your's works fine too. It gives me the curly braces and their inner content.

Comment: @Bernhard Since I'm bad at RegEx definition, I had no solution yet to post here. Sorry. Otherwise I would have posted my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be done without regex simply if you assume you want everything after the "}":

1. With `rsplit` - take what's after the "}"

   `s.rsplit("}")[-1]`
2. More efficiently with `rsplit` - split at most once

   `s.rsplit("}", 1)[-1]`
3. More efficient with `rfind`, doesn't allocate a string with the prefix we're throwing away

   `s[s.rfind("}")+1:]`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
s = '{http://datex2.eu/schema/2/2_0}nodeName'
search = re.search('{.*}(.*)',s)
print (search.group(1))
```

Comment: Please recall that the `*` is greedy.

Comment: what is the full text? what symbols are after 'nodeName' ? if the strting contains only one couple of curly braces - it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

Like this? [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xls8aE/2).

```
(?P<curlyStuff>\{[^}]+\})?(?P<nodeName>\w+)\b
```

Comment: That does the job. Thanks! Just need to put it to Python code. One more thing: what if the namespace (the curly braces) are not present. Then you regex doesn't find anything.

Comment: Updated to make the curlyStuff optional. See demo.